# How can you overwrite a JavaScript method?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-12

I need to overwrite Javascript Method, and exactky this method :

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/account/static/src/js/reconciliation/reconciliation_renderer.js#L338-L484

Could anyone explain what should I do to achieve this ?

Comment: Just edit the file on your server, what's the problem?

Comment: It is for an instance of odoo.sh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To override a `javascript` method by adding creating a new module follow this steps:

Create a `your_js_file_name.js` inside `static/src/js` folder, add it `assets_backend` templates like this.

```xml
<template id="assets_backend" name="hr assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/folder_name/static/src/js/your_js_file_name.js"></script>
        </xpath>
    </template>
```

In the `your_js_file_name.js` file define a new module like they did in `account` module, it's okay to have the same name, but make sure it starts with the folder name (`technical name` of your `module` like `account, sale, product...etc`):

```js
// just for debugin when you log in Odoo you should see this message
// if you don't see it this means that the js file is not loaded yet
// you need to make sure you upgrade the module the xml file that extend the assets_backed is in the manifest.
console.log('my ReconciliationRenderer is loaded);
odoo.define('folder_name.ReconciliationRenderer', function (require) {
      "use strict";

      var ReconciliationRenderer = require('account.ReconciliationRenderer');
      // you need to require any thing is used inside the code of the method too
      var qweb = core.qweb;  // like Qweb
      // override the method update of LineRenderer class
      ReconciliationRenderer.LineRenderer.include({
        update: function (state) {
            // you can call the original method using this
            this._super(state);
         }
      });

});
```

for most of `Javascript` method this should do it. Hope this gives you and idea of what you should do